# From multiprocess to multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I recently joined a team responsible for the enhancement of an existing 5-year old program.
It was developed with multithreading in mind, but not correctly implemented.

The solution is composed of multiple Windows Forms programs (let's call them Screen 1 and Screen 2).
Screen 1 can launch Screen 2 multiple times with differents parameters, but launches them as `Process`, not as `Threads`, `Tasks`, or by using `BackgroundWorker`.

Here is how it's done :

```
public void RunProcess(Arguments Arguments,string ExcutableName)
{
    Process Prc = new Process();
    Prc.StartInfo.FileName = ExcutableName;
    Prc.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments.GetProcessArguments();
    Prc.Start();
    _ListProcess.Add(Prc);
}
```

The processes are kept in memory and killed when Screen 1 closes.

I would like to refactor this in a cleaner way, going for a "single process" approach. What would you advise?

Comment: Does Screen 2 have any user interface code?

Comment: It looks like you should post your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not here

Comment: R u sure, you don't need a multi process envoirement?. You might require multiple app domains. Are we talking about foreground or Background threads? Have you concidered a MDI or floating window based Solution? What about Memory usage?... You should provide way more Input!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to port Screen 2's logic into the Screen 1 project, then replace the "Process" logic with threaded code.

Comment: I don't think this can be done easily. These programs have different entry points. They can be launched by Screen 1 or on their own.